# elisp: insert a double quote without the backslash

Tags: emacs, elisp

Here we go, a classical one: I am trying to surround a word with double quotes in elisp, but it inserts the backslash too !

I do:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string 
    "[A-za-z0-9]+: "   
    (lambda (match) (concat "\"" (s-replace ":" "" match) "\": ")) 
    "one tw2o: three")
```

The result includes the backslashes !

```
"one \"tw2o \": three"
```

my target is to process it with `json-read-from-string`.

I don't think it is a problem of printing in ielm because the json reading fails.

I have a working version using `with-temp-buffer` and `re-search-forward` but it's the same problem.

Any help and explanations appreciated ! Many thanks.

**edit**: if I use the string `(setq myjson "{one: \"1\", two: \"2\"}"`, my function works:

```
(json-read-from-string (replace-regexp-in-string "[A-za-z0-9]+: " 
  (lambda (match) (concat "\"" (s-replace ":" "" match) "\": ")) myjson))
```

but the result is

```
((two\  . "2")
 (one\  . "1"))
```

notice the backslash at the end of the key.

I deleted the edits that claimed that it works because this is still a pb.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, unfortunately, but would a work-around with a single quote work until someone comes up with the real answer?  `(replace-regexp-in-string "\\([A-za-z0-9]+:\\)" "'\\1'" "one tw2o: three")`

Comment: It doesn't, because I need double quotes for the json. However, I might have answered myself (see the edit), need to re-re-check ! PS: thanks for reminding me the use of \\1.

Comment: Re: the backslash edit: I believe that backslash is escaping a space, because you have a space at the end of your regexp.  Try using the regexp I had suggested in the first comment (but replacing the `'` with `\"`).

Comment: That looks better, I don't have the escaped whitespace. That looks like the answer. Thanks !

Comment: The original result doesn't actually have backslashes in it. Try `insert`ing it to see the real contents. `json-read-from-string` failed because `one "tw2o ": three` isn't valid json.